# What is causing Segmentation Fault in this code?

Tags: c

I am currently studying C implementations of Linux terminal commands in class but I can't seem to get the following example to run on my machine. I'm using the latest distro of Ubuntu. It will compile but with a warning. "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" it refers to the line with a=ctime(&n->ut_time); I found this code online. It is suppose to replicate the terminal command "Who" to display system users. I'm simply trying to study how it works but I cant seem to get it to run. Any help or explanations would be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/utsname.h>
#include<utmp.h>
int main(void)
{
 struct utmp *n;
 char *a;
 int i;
 setutent();
 n=getutent();
 while(n!=NULL)
 {
  if(n->ut_type==7)
  {
   printf("%-9s",n->ut_user);
   printf("%-12s",n->ut_line);
   a=ctime(&n->ut_time);
   printf(" ");
   for(i=4;i<16;i++)
   {
    printf("%c",a[i]);
   }
   printf(" (");
   printf("%s",n->ut_host);
   printf(")\n");
  }
  n=getutent();
 }
}
```

Comment: The compiler is telling you you've not got `#include <time.h>` so `ctime()` is assumed to return an `int` and not a `char *`.  All hell breaks loose (segmentation faults, etc) because you are not paying attention to the compiler warnings.  Remember, while you're learning C, the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  Its warnings should be heeded.  (When you know C reasonably well, you still pay attention to the compiler warnings - and make the code compile cleanly without warnings.  I use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and some extra options.)

Comment: As a note, you seem to be unfamiliar with `printf` format strings. You can replace your first three `printf` calls with `printf(%-9s%-12s ", n->ut_user, n->ut_line)` (the assignment to `a` doesn't infer with those calls) and your last three ones by `printf(" (%s)\n", n->ut_host)`. Take a look at some documentation.

Comment: And the loop could be replaced by `printf("%.*s", 12, &a[4]);` to print 12 characters starting at offset 4 in the string.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer*</sup>

The compiler is telling you you've not got `#include <time.h>` so `ctime()` is assumed to return an `int` and not a `char *`.  All hell breaks loose (segmentation faults, etc) because you are not paying attention to the compiler warnings.

Remember, while you're learning C, the compiler knows a lot more about C than you do.  Its warnings should be heeded.  (When you know C reasonably well, you still pay attention to the compiler warnings - and make the code compile cleanly without warnings.  I use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` and some extra options — usually `-Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wold-style-declaration`;  sometimes `-Wshadow`, `-pedantic`; and occasionally a few others.)